# How i am supposed to optimize my app on iphone 5 (previously letterboxed)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

When i try to publish my app, available before in letterbox mode for iphone 5, i get this error message "iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5." saying that my app is missing the image "Default-568h@2x" i deleted in order to make my app run in letterbox mode.
The app is supposed to be compatible with ios 5 and 6 and had been projected using storyboards!

Now i have no idea how to optimize my app for iphone 5? Can somenone explain to me how to letterbox again the app or optimize it for iphone 5? There's a third storyboard to compile?

Comment: Your app will be rejected if it runs "letterboxed" on iPhone 5

Comment: So? What, in detail, am i supposed to di?

Comment: Are you using storyboards for your application?

Comment: Follow the guidance given by the accepted answer in the linked question. What you have to do depends only on your app, and the layout you have used to create it. In one of my apps all I had to do was to add the 568h@2x launch image, because my autoresizingsmasks were setup properly. In another app I had to replace whole custom views because those views were not fit for iPhone 5 resolution. In another app it was a mix of both, some view controllers adapted automatically, others needed a new layout.

Comment: How do i add a new layout (screen in The storyboard) alternative for iPhone 5 and tell my app ti show that instead of The one project ed for iPhone 4?

Comment: You don't add a new layout for iPhone 5, you adjust the autoresizing masks on your iPhone 4 UI so that everything gets repositioned correctly on the wider/taller screen.

Comment: Ok, i feel like i'm about to discover a whole new world... ^^ What precisely is an autoresizing mask?

Comment: Got it! Using autoresizing mask i was able to restore my app even on iphone 5. For the sake of completeness, i suggest this documentation about resizing. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html